# How to get rows with values more than 2 in at least 2 columns?

Tags: awk

I am trying to extract row where value is >=2 in atleast two column. My input file look like this

```
gain,top1,sos1,pho1
ATC1,0,0,0
ATC2,1,2,1
ATC3,6,6,0
ATC4,1,1,2
```

and my awk script look like this

```
cat input_file | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","};{count>=0;for(i=2; i<4; i++) {if($i!=0) {count++}};if (count>=2){print $0}}'
```

which doesn't give me the expected output that should be

```
gain,top1,sos1,pho1
ATC3,6,6,0
```

What is the problem with this script. Thanks.

Comment: you have to reset the counter as `count=0` for one.  you're checking `$i!=0` instead of `$i>=2` is another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'FNR>1{f=0; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)if($i>=2)f++}f>=2 || FNR==1' file
```

Or below one, print and go to next line immediately after finding 2 values (Reasonably faster)

```
awk -F, 'FNR>1{f=0; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){ if($i>=2)f++; if(f>=2){ print; next} } }FNR==1' file
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -F, '                                # call awk and set field separator as comma
         FNR>1{                          # we wanna skip header to be checked so, if no of records related to current file is greater than 1
                 f=0;                    # set variable f = 0
                 for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)    # start looping from second field to no of fields in record/line/row
                 { 
                    if($i>=2)f++;        # if field value is greater than 2 increment variable f
                    if(f>=2)             # if we got 2 values ? then
                    { 
                       print;            # print record/line/row
                       next              # we got enough go to next line
                    } 
                 } 
               }FNR==1                   # if first record being read then print in fact if FNR==1 we get boolean true, so it does default operation print $0, that is current record/line/row
        ' file
```

**Input**

```
$ cat file
gain,top1,sos1,pho1
ATC1,0,0,0
ATC2,1,2,1
ATC3,6,6,0
ATC4,1,1,2
```

**Output-1**

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR>1{f=0; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)if($i>=2)f++}f>=2 || FNR==1' file
gain,top1,sos1,pho1
ATC3,6,6,0
```

**Output-2** (Reasonably faster)

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR>1{f=0; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){ if($i>=2)f++; if(f>=2){ print; next} } }FNR==1' file
gain,top1,sos1,pho1
ATC3,6,6,0
```

Comment: can you explain the script for a novice like me? Thanks.

Comment: @pali: added explanation

Answer (score 0):

hacky `awk`, handles the header as well

```
$ awk -F, '($2>=2) + ($3>=2) + ($4>=2) > 1' file

gain,top1,sos1,pho1
ATC3,6,6,0
```

or,

```
$ awk -F, 'function ge2(x) {return x>=2?1:0}  
           ge2($2) + ge2($3) + ge2($4) > 1' file

gain,top1,sos1,pho1
ATC3,6,6,0
```

Answer (score 0):

@pali: @try:
Hope this should be much faster.

```
awk '{Q=$0;}(gsub(/,[2-9]/,"",Q)>=2) || FNR==1'  Input_file
```

Here I am putting line's value into a variable named Q then, from Q variable globally substituting all the matches , then digits from 2 to 9 to NULL. Then checking it's count if that is greater or equal than 2, if either it's global substitution's value is greater than 2 or line number is 1 then it should print the current line.

Comment: fyi you can use `gsub(/,[2-9]/,"&")` instead of `{Q=$0;}(gsub(/,[2-9]/,"",Q))`. Obviously this approach only works if all numbers are single digits which IS what the OP showed in their sample input.

Comment: multi-digits will also satisfy the condition since it will be greater than the threshold (but still assumes all positive numbers)